# How to debug Halide internal error with CodeGen_LLVM

Tags: llvm, halide

I have problems finding the source of an error message reported by JIT-compiled pipeline with halide.

The log message is:

```
Internal Error at Halide-release_2019_08_27/halide/src/CodeGen_LLVM.cpp:2815 triggered by user code at :
Condition failed: append_string:
```

The LLVM_code at the following lines is:

```
llvm::Function *append_string  = module->getFunction("halide_string_to_string");
internal_assert(append_string);
```

I'm using halide release build from **2019_08_27** on Ubuntu 18.04.

The pipeline runs without any errors until somebody wanted to use the Halide::print() for debugging.
I've checked a small test pipeline and print seem to work.

My problem now is to find our bug in a very complex pipeline. Could somebody explain the source of this bug and what I need to check in my code to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

That means the function "halide_string_to_string" was not found in the runtime, which would be very odd for CPU targets. Hrm, I wonder if you're trying to use print inside a Func scheduled on a GPU or DSP? I could easily imagine that being broken.

Comment: Thank you. That was fast. We do schedule on GPU.
Switching to CPU solved it.